# Does MS-Teams only support a single video in the browser?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I tried Teams in Chrome because I am getting tired of a bug on the Mac desktop app. I noticed it would only show me the person who was talking, rather than multiple people at once.

Is this just a limitation of the web-app version?